# SystemVerilog Mux design with "always_comb and tri state variables"

Tags: multiplexer, system-verilog, synthesis, rtl

Here is my code for a mux inside an `always_comb` block. I'm designing a mux with combinatorial logic where I use the shortened `if-else` block to either assign one of the input paths or high impedance (Z). I expected this to realize a mux, but it looks like a priority encoder as one of the four input combinations work.

I've attached the waveform from Vivado simulator. I'm not sure why this code doesn't work as a mux.

```
module sv_mux(
    input logic [3:0] in0,
    input logic [3:0] in1,
    input logic [3:0] in2,
    input logic [3:0] in3,
    input logic [1:0] sel,
    output logic [3:0] out
);

always_comb
begin
    //using tristate buffer implementation
    `ifdef USING_TRI_STATE
    out = (sel==2'b11) ? in3 : 4'bZ;
    out = (sel==2'b00) ? in0 : 4'bZ;
    out = (sel==2'b01) ? in1 : 4'bZ;
    out = (sel==2'b10) ? in2 : 4'bZ;
    `endif
end

endmodule
```

Here is the tb:

```
module sv_mux_tb;

logic [3:0] in0,in1,in2,in3,out;
logic [1:0] sel;

sv_mux dut(in0,in1,in2,in3,sel,out);

initial begin
    {in0,in1,in2,in3} = 16'b0;
    sel = 2'b0;
    #10
    in0 = 4'd3;
    in1 = 4'd7;
    in2 = 4'd15;
    in3 = 4'd10;
    #10
    sel = 2'b01;
    #10
    sel = 2'b10;
    #10
    sel = 2'b11;
    #10
    sel = 2'b10;
end
endmodule
```

One of the texts offered this code as an alternate implementation using tri-state buffers, but this doesn't work either. error is "out has multiple driver"

```
assign out = (sel == 2'b00) ? in0 : 4'bZ,
       out = (sel == 2'b01) ? in1 : 4'bZ,
       out = (sel == 2'b10) ? in2 : 4'bZ,
       out = (sel == 2'b11) ? in3 : 4'bZ;
```

[image]

Comment: I am able to implement with a case statement, but I want to understand what is wrong with the tri-state implementation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the last assignment to `out` wins because the simulator executes blocking assignments in order.

You should use a `case` statement for a mux:

```
always_comb
begin
    case (sel)
        2'b00: out = in0;
        2'b01: out = in1;
        2'b10: out = in2;
        2'b11: out = in3;
    endcase
end
```

In this code, only one assignment will be executed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented mux with case. But my question was to understand the mistake in the above code. If concurrent assignment statements are inside the always_comb, why should the last statement win. I assumed if the logic was given Z by other drivers(through tri state buffers) and a valid value by one, that should result in the valid output being propagated.

Comment: @NishanthReddy:  You're welcome.  See my updated answer.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the solution. I guess the only thing unanswered is what would the code for a mux implementation with tri-state buffers as I saw this code as a possible implementation of mux as an example:

`assign out = (sel==2’b0) ? in0 : 1’bz, 
out = (sel==2’b1) ? in1 : 1’bz, 
out = (sel==2’b2) ? in2 : 1’bz, 
out = (sel==2’b3) ? in3 : 1’b z;`

Comment: @NishanthReddy You're welcome again.  Since you are a new user, the way to say "thanks" is to [Accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer.  If you have a question about some new code, go ahead and post it as a new Question.