# System Verilog Mux Implementation using tri-state buffers

Tags: fpga, verilog, multiplexer, system-verilog, tri-state

I found a **verilog** implementation of a mux using tri-state buffers in the document [UMD Lab Tutorial on Verilog](http://classweb.ece.umd.edu/enee245.S2015/Lab7.pdf) (I'm not a student, graduated 2 years ago :))

```
module mux(input wire [7:0] in0,
           input wire [7:0] in1,
           input wire [7:0] in2,
           input wire [7:0] in3,
           input wire [1:0] sel,
           output reg [7:0] out)
assign out = (sel == 2'b00) ? in0 : 8'bZ ,
       out = (sel == 2'b01) ? in1 : 8'bZ ,
       out = (sel == 2'b10) ? in2 : 8'bZ ,
       out = (sel == 2'b11) ? in3 : 8'bZ ;
endmodule
```

When I tried this with **SystemVerilog**, I got the multiple driver error.

Can someone show me alternate code? I know using case statement will simplify things. I'm just wondering if its possible with tri-state and if we can physically implement mux with tri-state buffers on an Fpga platform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SystemVerilog Mux design with "always\_comb and tri state variables"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590167/systemverilog-mux-design-with-always-comb-and-tri-state-variables)

Comment: you probably used `output out`, which means `output var logic out`, which doesn't support multiple drivers. What you need is `output wire logic out` or simply `output wire`.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, I asked the previous question as well. Now I'm clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the compiler error by changing `output reg` to `output wire`. See [this post](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/) explaining why multiple drivers are not allowed to the same variable.

But FPGAs typically do not support tri-state drivers within the device. You can certainly do this on a bus between FPGA devices.

Comment: It works now thanks!! I was also seeing if fpgas use tri-state buffers, found that these units are mostly used at output bidirectional pins and buses. I guess I was intending to use this kind of implementation when I encounter designing bus logic.